# How to create a SQL report so that if a date is prior to reporting start date, then I would use the Report Start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

I'm trying to create a sql report that captures the length of a patient stay. Basically what I'm doing is if a patient is admitted on 12-12-2013 and discharged on 1-31-2014 I'm going to run a report that will count the length of stay starting on the report date range which is 1-1-2014 to 1-31-2014. I want the datediff to only start on 1-1-2014 not 12-12-2013.

This is how I have my sql for now, but I know it is incorrect

```
 declare @from_date date, @to_date date

 set @from_date = '07/01/14'
 set @to_date = '07/31/14'

 SELECT 
   datediff(dd, @from_date, @to_date) LOS, 
   PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE,
   pt_admission.TERMINATION_DATE

 FROM O_DATASET O_DATASET
    INNER JOIN PT_ADMISSION PT_ADMISSION ON 
    (PT_ADMISSION.CLINICAL_SET_ID = O_DATASET.CLINICAL_SET_ID)
     where admit_date <= @from_date
```

Comment: Since you mention datediff function I assume your using MS SQL?

Comment: Yes I am using ms sql

Comment: What's your error message on your sql when you try to run this?

Comment: I dont get an error, but it doesn't use the @from date for those patients who admit dates are before 1-1-2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` statement to set the @from_date variable.  Here's your sample adjusted with the @from_date set based on the value of the report start date.

```
declare @report_start_date date
declare @from_date date, @to_date date

SET @report_start_date = '7/15/14'

set @from_date = '07/01/14'
set @to_date = '07/31/14'

-- adjust for report start date
SET @from_date = CASE WHEN @report_start_date > @from_date 
                THEN @report_start_date ELSE @from_date END

SELECT 
  datediff(dd, @from_date, @to_date) LOS, 
  PT_ADMISSION.ADMIT_DATE,
  pt_admission.TERMINATION_DATE

FROM O_DATASET O_DATASET
   INNER JOIN PT_ADMISSION PT_ADMISSION ON 
   (PT_ADMISSION.CLINICAL_SET_ID = O_DATASET.CLINICAL_SET_ID)
    where admit_date <= @from_date
```